# Find the 3 angles of the hyperbolic triangle

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

A(0,5) B(0,2) C(4,2)

In Euclidean geometry the three points given are the vertices of a right-angled triangle. Find the three angles of the hyperbolic triangle with vertices A,B,C. Find the hyperbolic lengths of the three sides.

I know the sum of the interior angles of a hyperbolic triangle are less than 180 but I have no idea where to go from here.

Comment: Are you using the upper half-plane representation of the hyperbolic plane?

Comment: yes i believe so

Comment: Does [Poincare half-plane model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_half-plane_model) answer the question?

Comment: no it doesn't. That still doesn't tell me where to start

Comment: The way that I'm interpreting the question is that you need to just plug in the points $A$, $B$, and $C$ into the distance formula (third line in the metric section).  So, how should the question be interpreted?

Comment: My starting point is trying to find the angle measures

Answer (score 1):

To find the distances, you can plug the points into the [Poincare half-plane model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_half-plane_model) distance formula.

To find the angles, one way to do this is to find the lines between the points.  In the upper half-plane model, the geodesics are vertical lines and semicircles which are perpendicular to the $x$-axis.  Therefore, you can find that $A$ and $B$ are on the line $x=0$.  The points $B$ and $C$ are on the semicircle $(x-2)^2+y^2=8$.  The points $A$ and $C$ are on the semicircle with center $(t,0)$ where $t$ solves $t^2+5^2=(4-t)^2+2^2$ (that is, the point on the $x$ axis that is the same distance two $A$ and $C$).  Finally, you can take the angles between these curves as hyperbolic space is locally Euclidean.

Comment: funny that while in the euclidean case $\angle B$ is the right angle , in the poincare halfplane case  $\angle A$ is the greater one.